# Ubuntu 20.04 secondary (Integrated graphics) monitor not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

My secondary VGA monitor using AMD integrated graphics (plugged into motherboard) will not work at the same time as my main monitor (plugged into NVIDIA 1050 Ti).

I do not want to buy an adapter to plug both monitors into the graphics card, as they generally always reduce video quality, so I will be using the motherboard connection. I have also searched the Internet for around two hours total trying to get this to work properly, but no Stack Exchange posts seem to fit my exact scenario.

The secondary monitor is stuck on the BIOS boot screen. Here's what I've found makes the secondary monitor have different outputs so far:

- Using my dual-boot of Windows, both monitors work.
- Attempting to change the BIOS to have integrated graphics as the default, the secondary monitor works in the TTY, and for the GRUB menu.
- xrandr -q does not show any output containing the other monitor.
- Disconnecting the graphics card, the secondary monitor works as the primary one (however, of course, a hardware acceleration error appears.)

I have tried numerous different X window managers, none of them seem to work with both. I've also tried switching to TTY with integrated graphics as primary in BIOS, and it works. When running `startx xclock` in that TTY, it freezes the secondary monitor, and switches to the primary monitor.

I have the NVIDIA Control Panel installed, and have tried switching from Performance, to Quality, and to Performance again, with no luck.

TL;DR: It seems an X or GRUB configuration error is causing my secondary monitor to not work with AMD integrated graphics as well as the NVIDIA 1050 Ti card.

Edit: This arrangement of devices has worked in the past, and I have been able to get this to work before. The issue is likely software-based.

Answer (score 0):

What is your primary monitor connected by? (VGI, HDMI, Displayport)

Usually, you can run 2 monitors off 2 gpus if you have a SLI bridge, but because this is an integrated graphics card (AMD) and a completely different brand of dedicated GPU (NVIDIA), It wouldn't be possible without connecting both cables into the GPU. You have 2 options:

- Buy a VGA to Displayport converter from a reputable source
- Multiseat (Turn your computer into 2)

Why does this happen? After inserting your dedicated GPU into your computer, your integrated GPU disables itself because the integrated GPU uses your CPU, which lightens the load off your CPU, improving performance, this is also why it's recommended to plug your monitors into 1 GPU

In extremely rare cases, it will work.

Comment: HDMI. This shouldn't matter, though. Also, next time you ask questions under a post, please try to use the "comment" section rather than posting an answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even know that button existed, Thanks!

Comment: Usually 1050 TI's have a hdmi, and a displayport on the back of them, and sometimes a VGA, do you only have a HDMI input on your graphics card?

Comment: I have HDMI, Displayport, and DVI (afaik).

Comment: Does your secondary monitor have anything other than a VGA input?

Comment: No, it only has VGA.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Vexicle, I've forgotten to add this to my question, but this whole arrangement has worked in the past, as far as I can remember. I'll edit it now. Also, it works on Windows, why wouldn't it work on Linux too?

Comment: Looks like you've got some luck, have you tried older versions of ubuntu? Also forgot to mention that it's extremely rare that can run. It's not meant to either because both have completely different drivers, with different methods of projecting onto the screen.

Comment: No, I've not. I don't think that would be a useful thing to try though, as if I was reinstalling Ubuntu on a separate partition, I would need a lot more storage than I currently have. The Windows test is likely all I needed to do.

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure how to help you, but good luck on fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on 22.04 after updating the kernel. What worked for me was

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```